# Regular expression in Aptana Studio Find and Replace

Tags: regex, replace, ide, aptana

I'm trying to do a find and replace in many php files in aptana. To ease my job i did a regular expression that finds what i need but replacing does not work.

This is what exactly I'm trying to do:

```
 Replace _e("This is a sentence.");
 with    _e("This is a sentenct.","mydomain");
```

This is the regex i use for finding matches:

```
\_e\(\"([\a-z-]+)\"\) --> it works
```

This is the regex i use for replacing the matches

```
\_e\(\"([\a-z-]+)\",\"mydomain\")    --> It does not work,
```

This is what It replaces with:

```
_e("([-z-]+)","mydomain");  --> bad result
```

**EDIT:** Also, i need my regex to find special characters like ă, ș

Answer (score 3):

You seems to have not very well understand how replacement strings work. A replacement string is a normal string without regex symbols inside. The only difference with a literal string is that you can add backreferences from your search pattern.

Example:

```
search:  (_e\("[^"]*")\)
replace: $1,"mydomain")
```

pattern details:

```
(          # open the capture group 1
    _e     # literal: _e
    \("    # literal: (" (literal parenthesis must be escaped since it has a
           # special meaning in a pattern (to define groups)) 
    [^"]*  # all that is not a ", zero or more times
    "      # literal "
)          # close the capture group 1
\)         # literal closing parenthesis
```

`$1` in the replacement string is a backreference and refers to the content of the capture group 1 from the search pattern. Note that the closing parenthesis is not escaped since it has no special meaning in a replacement string.

*(Don't forget to check the .* checkbox in the search/replace dialog box)*